# Get the value from the soap string

Tags: php, xml, soap

php curl gets such a string. How can I extract the "balance" value from it?

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<ns2:getActiveBonusAccountsResponse xmlns:ns2="http://processing.cards.crystals.ru/">
<return>
<balance>26</balance>
<bonusAccountId>72055</bonusAccountId>
<bonusAccountsTypeVO>
<accountsType>MONEY</accountsType>
<bonusAccountTypeCode>4211</bonusAccountTypeCode>
<bonusAccountTypeId>4211</bonusAccountTypeId>
<bonusAccountsTypeName>Основной</bonusAccountsTypeName>
<bonusCourse>100</bonusCourse>
<currencyCourse>100</currencyCourse>
<entirePurchase>true</entirePurchase>
<writeOffAllAmountAtOnce>false</writeOffAllAmountAtOnce>
</bonusAccountsTypeVO>
<enabled>true</enabled>
</return>
</ns2:getActiveBonusAccountsResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

We tried

```
$soap = simplexml_load_string($soap_response);
$soap->registerXPathNamespace('ns2', 'http://processing.cards.crystals.ru/');
$test = (string) $soap->xpath('//ns2:return/ns2:balance[1]')[0];
var_dump($test);
```

but it didn't work

Comment: OK, this happens a lot to me when writing answers, the question gets closed. Anyway, here's how to do it: https://3v4l.org/Gjrsm

Comment: More specifically: https://3v4l.org/NgANp . But the duplicate shows you the various possible techniques, and explains why it didn't work with the basic approach

Comment: Don't make your question vaguer...I rolled back your last edit. If anything it would be more useful if it was made more specific instead

Comment: The key in this case is to notice that `<return>` and `<balance>` are *not* prefixed `ns2:` in the XML, so aren't using the namespace defined by `xmlns:ns2`. In fact, they're not in _any_ namespace, because there's no default `xmlns` attribute provided, so you don't need any namespacing in your XPath. https://3v4l.org/XATT8